# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask my question about clothes making sounds?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask about what causes my clothes (usually upper body clothes, such as sweaters) to make certain soft sounds when taking them off or moving them after sitting in front of the computer (not moving a lot) for a long time?

My guess is that it has to do with the heat produced by the computer, some type of radiation or both, but I would like to know more details about it.

I'm thinking the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) site might be the most appropriate but I'm not confident about it.

---

Edit: [My question in the Physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526481).

Comment: That sounds ok for Physics. Here's an existing similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168293/123208 Your question may get closed as a duplicate of that one...

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you. I did not found that question on my quick search. It does indeed seem to approach my question even though it unfortunatly does so in complex terms for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with thinking about Physics Stack Exchange. What you describe does seem to be a physics phenomenon, and that site has some questions about physics in every day life, e.g.

- [How to avoid getting shocked by static electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4180/77072)
- [Why is walking up stairs harder than walking normally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216829/77072)
- [Should you run when under rain?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19499/77072)

The first example question in their [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is another example of this:

- [Why does one experience a short pull in the wrong direction when a vehicle stops?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629/77072)

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to know that it's on topic with one of the network's sites.